# When I do POST request on golang api using POSTMAN I successfully receive the jwt token as a cookie but when I do it from browser I get no cookie

Tags: ajax, go, cors, jwt, setcookie

I have made an API in golang. Backend and frontend are running on separate servers. When I test the API with POSTMAN everything works fine and I receive the cookie containing the jwt token but when I do the request from the frontend then no cookie is received.

Here is the middleware for handling CORS:

```
func corsHandler(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // origin := r.Header.Get("Origin")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:5000")
        if r.Method == "OPTIONS" {
            w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
            w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE")

            w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, access-control-allow-origin")
            return
        }
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

Following is the cookie generator:

```
    jwtCookie := &http.Cookie{
        Name:   "jwtToken",
        Secure: false,
        HttpOnly: true,
        Value:    tokenString,
        Expires:  expiryTime,
    }

    http.SetCookie(w, jwtCookie)
    w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
```

Following is the ajax request:

```
       $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/signin',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                "username": $('#username').val(),
                "password": $('#password').val()
            }),
            xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(message) {
                console.log(message.responseJSON);
            }
        });
```

In firefox the response header looks like this:
[As you can see in image 1, the cookie is received in header but it is not visible in storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zOsF.png)

In chrome the response header looks like:
[there is no cookie visible in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPX8e.png)

I am stuck on this for quite a long time. Any help would be valuable :)

Comment: Your CORS allowed origin isn't the same as the URL in your JavaScript - are your API and UI being served from the same port?

Comment: No, they are served on different ports. Frontend: localhost:5000, backend: localhost:8080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add `w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")` for all the requests and not just OPTIONS preflight request and also it turned out that chrome was not showing the cookie in storage but it was present and working as expected, later I checked in firefox and the cookie was visible in storage.

Answer (score 0):

In your server response, set `HttpOnly` to false and in chrome, go to console and type `document.cookie`. You should see the cookie set by the server.

The other option is, leave `HttpOnly` set to true. In chrome, open developer tools, click on `Application` tab, you should see `Cookies` under `Storage`. Click on `Cookies` and you should see the cookie set by the server.